# Kivy: issue with event defined variables

Tags: python, kivy

I am a complete noob on **kivy** (and object oriented approach in python programming) and I struggle trying to implement a simple file checker (I think I am missing a key element of kivy's logic). I want my app to indicate **whether my file is a csv**.

```
class CsvLoader(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CsvLoader, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.btn = Button(text='Please, Drag and Drop your CSV')
        self.add_widget(self.btn)

        csv = Window.bind(on_dropfile=self._on_file_drop) # this is the s*** part: how to get the file_path?

        if str(csv).split('.')[-1] != "csv'" and csv != None:
            self.clear_widgets()
            btn_error = Button(text='Wrong file type')
            self.add_widget(btn_error)


    def _on_file_drop(self, window, file_path):
        return file_path


class VisualizeMyCsv(App):
    def build(self):
        return CsvLoader()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VisualizeMyCsv().run()
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: How do you want me to indicate that it is a .csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the function bind you link an action, which in your case `on_dropfile` that triggers when you place a file, with a function that is called when the event is triggered, so the logic must be done within that method:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

class CsvLoader(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CsvLoader, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.btn = Button(text='Please, Drag and Drop your CSV')
        self.add_widget(self.btn)

        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self._on_file_drop)

    def _on_file_drop(self, window, file_path):
        if str(file_path).split('.')[-1] == "csv'":
            print(file_path)
            # here you must indicate that it is a .csv file
        else:
            # it is not a .csv file
            print("it is not a .csv file")

class VisualizeMyCsv(App):
    def build(self):
        return CsvLoader()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VisualizeMyCsv().run()
```